# How to position the navigator series in highstock?

Tags: highcharts

I want to fix the navigator handles position at last. The navigator handles are full expanded when I reload the page.

I want to fix the navigator handles position like this.

[image]

In this below image , I manually adjusted the handles position at last. I want to fix the position by default.

[image]

Comment: You need some kind of approximation/flattening or what?

Comment: @madhead , I want to fix the navigator handles position by default.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the xAxis range in ms: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.range

Answer (score 1):

You can use setExtremes function http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes()

Answer (score 0):

use xAxis.range :

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
    xAxis: {
        range: 6 * 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000 // six months
    },
    ....
}
```

demo [fidder](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/xaxis/range/)